# Why is there two sets of black and white wires connected together in my wall?

Tags: wiring, kitchens

[image: tore down walls to put up new dry wall and found this just exactly the way it appears here]

Don't understand what this is, I was told it was probley a splice in the wires to extend wiring but I thought white had to be with white, black with black and ground to ground.....is this something that needs to be in a junction box ??

Comment: This definitely needs to be in a junction box, and moreover, the splice needs to use a listed connection method such as wire nuts, not just twist-and-tape.

Comment: Is it possible that this box was at one point a light switch that was removed?  If those used to be switch loops, it would explain why black and white within the same cable are connected.

Comment: The photo shows them taped together but it is unknown whether or not they are a connection between the black and the white wires,  have you taken the black electrical tape off to see if the wires have been stripped of insulation and connected together or if the insulation was left on and they were just taped together. ??

Comment: Is any of that live?  Is this box at switch level, receptacle level, or maybe up in the attic floor?  I would not be surprised if these were wires that are no longer in use.

Comment: Agree with batsplatsterson.  A non-contact voltage detector can tell you if anything is live without having to cut into the bundles, but switch loop or dead, disconnected wires are the two reasons I see.

Comment: Yes it is at switch level , I have not yet stripped the electric tape off to see if the insulation was stripped back and they are really connected .. And yes it is still live ... I wanted to get some advise before I went pulling tape off and wire butting them up to put in junction box .... now when I do the wire nuts do I leave them the way they are or do I put white with white and black with black ?? Thank ya for advise tho

Answer (score 2):

It could be a switch loop, that box would be legal as a junction if a cover was installed. I would want to clean that up with wire nuts and tuck the wires in the box and add a cover.

Comment: Yes it is at switch level , I have not yet stripped the electric tape off to see if the insulation was stripped back and they are really connected .. And yes it is still live ... I wanted to get some advise before I went pulling tape off and wire butting them up to put in junction box .... now when I do the wire nuts do I leave them the way they are or do I put white with white and black with black ?? Thank ya for advise tho

Comment: The way they are is usually the best advice. I would trace them and figure out what they power or used to power.